# Quelle est la meilleure façon d’apprendre à utiliser le subjonctif ?

Tags: subjonctif, apprentissage

Ça fait presque un an et demi que j’entends, pratique, et utilise le subjonctif et je ne maîtrise toujours pas les expressions de base.

Je n’ai pas trop de problèmes quand je conjugue mais pour les expressions basiques, je n’ai presque aucune idée, à part quelques expressions, du mode à utiliser, surtout pour des expressions comme : *accepter que, avouer et admettre que, il est temps que, dire que, etc.* (en particulier celles qui n'exigent le subjonctif qu'à la forme négative).

Alors, vaut-il mieux simplement mémoriser tout comme sur ce site [lawlessfrench](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/subjunctivisor/), ou est-il possible d'acquérir, d'une façon ou d'une autre, quelle qu’elle soit, une logique ou une intuition pour choisir le mode à utiliser ? (Ou peut-être y-a-t-il d’autres suggestions ?)

Merci d’avance!

Avant qu’on ne me le demande, j’ai choisi de ne pas mémoriser tout cela parce que je trouve qu’il y a beaucoup de fautes sur le site lawlessfrench.

Par exemple, l’expression *il est improbable que* n’est pas présentée dans les deux cas : affirmatif (subjonctif) et négatif (indicatif). J’ai déjà posé la question à quelqu’un qui est probablement français, et, sur le site, il n’y a aucun cas où l’affirmatif est employé au subjonctif, ni où le négatif est employé à l’indicatif. Ce n'est qu'une erreur parmi d'autres.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the *il est improbable que* lawlessfrench error ?

Answer (score 2):

Il n'est peut-être pas inutile de  répéter que pour se mettre en tête cet aspect du français, c'est à dire pour identifier sans erreur où le subjonctif est indispensable, sans avoir à penser consciemment, la meilleure manière c'est d'investir du temps dans la lecture ; ce doit être une lecture choisie : les articles de revues sérieuses et la littérature dans les humanités sont de bonnes sources, de même que des romans dans la littérature du siècle dernier ; néanmoins, l'usage en ce qui concerne le subjonctif a amorcé un certain changement et il y aura toujours des cas pour lesquels même un lecteur moyen restera dans le  doute.
Cet exercice soutenu de lecture sera en même temps profitable dans tous les aspects de la langue et un jour arrivera où comme on le dit en anglais on pourra voir la lumière à l'autre bout du tunnel, mais il ne faut pas compter sur moins de quelques années de persévérance. Il y a une chose importante qu'il faut prendre en compte  dans cet exercice de lecture : il faut  se ménager un niveau de difficulté pas trop grand ; par exemple, il ne faut pas commencer par des ouvrages philosophiques comme  ceux d'Émannuel Kant, mais des traductions de la philosophie de Montaigne  en français moderne seront assez tôt des ouvrages abordables ; en d'autres mots, il faut toujours avoir une compréhension substantielle de ce qu'on lit ; ce qui importe ensuite c'est d'être intéressé dans ce qu'on lit.
Il faut bien comprendre que si après plusieurs années de lecture les règles de grammaires deviendront plus faciles à assimiler, on n'aura toujours pas appris la grammaire, seulement elle deviendra  moins rébarbative et on l'apprendra plus vite comme on aura acquis une masse de connaissances qui peuvent vérifier les règles et qu'elle sera alors plus intéressante.

Ne mémoriser de longues listes en aucun cas ; les listes sont excellentes pour certaines choses comme la vérification lorsqu'on veut être vraiment sûr et aussi pour  acquérir une notion générale de la difficulté ou pour apprécier le progrès que l'on aura pu faire ; par exemple, à n'importe quel moment opportun, vous pouvez consulter une liste comme [celle-ci](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4238) et la passer en revue en considérant peut-être en particulier des locutions que vous avez acquises et en vérifiant de tête par un exemple improvisé si le mode auquel vous semblez habitué est bien celui qui est stipulé ; vous pouvez aussi lire à propos de celles que vous ne connaissez pas encore.
Il est possible cependant que vous ayez l'avantage d'une mémoire exceptionnelle et dans ce cas il devient difficile de dire que la mémorisation serait une perte de temps.

[LawlessFrench](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/subjunctivisor/il-est-improbable/) est correct ; si vous passez ces pages en revue ([il est improbable que](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22il+est+improbable+que%22&lr=lang_fr&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1fr,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv-pK1_5vuAhWIHRQKHcRDBToQpwUIJA&biw=1920&bih=1005&dpr=1), [il n'est pas improbable que](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22il+n%27est+pas+improbable+que%22&lr=lang_fr&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1fr,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRuZ-A_pvuAhWfAGMBHfZcCjoQpwUIJA&biw=1920&bih=1005&dpr=1)) vous constatez que le subjonctif est toujours utilisé pour la première et que pour la seconde il peut ne pas être utilisé, mais plutôt exceptionnellement. Ceci confirme ce que je mentionne ci-dessus : il existe une tendance vers le changement.